# Cannot set natural color for Sentinel-2 raster data

Tags: raster, qgis-3, color, sentinel-2

I'm trying to create a new raster data with nature color (B4-B3-B2) for the left raster data in QGIS 3, but I failed. This should be similar to the right one.

Both of them were downloaded from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home.

- **The left raster data**:

> S2B_MSIL2A_20200227T030659_N0214_R075_T48PXS_20200227T071451

- **The right raster data**:

> S2B_MSIL2A_20200227T030659_N0214_R075_T48PYS_20200227T071451

[image: Two raster data combined]

How can I solve this problem?

---

I just followed this step.
First I imported B4, B3, B2 raster bands

[image]

Then I build a new virtual raster

[image]

Next I assigned the bands to the channel. I don't know why there is no band 4 in even thought I've added before.

[image]

However it's still not working.

---

It's worked!
However I don't know why the band order is 3-2-4 for R-G-B instead of 4-3-2.

Could anybody explain it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the bands in your left image are assigned to the channel like this:

Red: Band 2; Green: Band 4; Blue: Band 3

[image: 2-4-3]

When you assign them as intended (Red: Band 4; Green: Band 3; Blue: Band 2), the image looks like this

[image: 4-3-2]

When you create a Virtual Raster with different files for each band the bands will be numbered sequentially starting from 1, regardless of which Sentinel band the files correspond to. You need to keep track of this correspondence yourself - in particular, you have to pay attention to the way the files are ordered in the "Multiple selection" window of the "Build Virtual Raster" dialog. You can reorder the files there before adding them by dragging and dropping the individual entries. If you order them like in the screenshot below the Virtual Raster will have the correct band assignment from the start:

[image]